# Extracting matches from perl regex using global modifier in foreach loop

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract matched parts from a string using the global modifier.

Consider:

```
my $a="A B C";
my $b="A B C";

foreach ($a =~ /(\w)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
while ($b =~ /(\w)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Output:

```
C
C
C
A
B
C
```

I am confused; why does the `while` loop work, whereas the `foreach` loop does not? (It prints `C` three times).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: change body of the first loop to `print "$_\n"`.

When a global regex match is used as a list, it evaluates to a list of all captures (here: `qw(A B C)`). The `foreach` loop iterates over this list, and sets `$_` to each item in turn. However, `$1` points to the first capture group of the last (successful) match. As the list of matches is produced before the looping begins, this will point to the last match the whole time.

When a global regex match is used as an iterator in a `while`, it matches the regex and if successful executed the loop body, then tries again. Because only one match is produced at the time, `$1` always refers to the first capture group in the current match.

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
foreach ($a =~ /(\w)/g)
```

Evaluates the regular expression in list context, and iterates through each item in the list. `$1` is the last thing was captured in the brackets when constructing the list. The following should work:

```
foreach my $matched ($a =~ /(\w)/g) {
  print "$matched\n";
}
```

However, the `while` syntax is usually best since it does not construct and store that temporary list.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the memory efficiency of the while loop over the foreach.  For huge strings, the foreach could gobble up a bit of memory.